# Moving around operators under integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

When trying to find the normalization constant of 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}H_m(x)H_n(x) \,dx$$

for the Hermite polynomials $$H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2},$$

my reference shows that we can use this equation once in the integral to get
$$(-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}H_m(x) e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}\,dx = (-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_m(x) \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}\,dx. $$

I'm wondering, why can the exponentials cancel out if $H_m(x)$ is technically an operator (unless they commute)?

Comment: $H_m(x)$ is a Hermite polynomial i.e. a real function. Multiplication is commutative in the reals.

Comment: you only have polynomials $H_n(x)$ and $H_m(x)$. No operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H_m(x)$ is not an operator, or rather, it is an ordinary function of $x$. The $d^n/dx^n$ acts only on the $e^{-x^2}$. So for example $H_1(x) = -e^{x^2} \frac{d}{dx} (e^{-x^2}) = 2x $. There are alternative definitions that do not use derivatives, such as
$$ e^{2tx-t^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}. $$